# Debezium MySQL Connector not showing change event key

Tags: mysql, debezium

I am not able to get the change event key in my kafka topic whenever I insert a record in my MySQL table.

As per the documentation - https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-change-event-keys, I should be getting the change event key as well. But I am getting only the change event value schema and payload

I have set both parameters to true

```
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
```

Still I am not able to see the change event key schema.
I do see change even value schema and metadata schema and payload.

Anything I am missing ?